# Find multiple strings and replace with single string in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

Is it possible to do a "find and replace" with the following?

```
UPDATE __table__ SET __column__ = replace(__column__, ' ', '_');
```

How do I define an array of strings to be found (`','`, `';'`, `':'`, `' '`) to replace with `'_'`?

Comment: Use `regexp_replace`

Comment: @CraigRinger Tried it with `'{',',':',' '}'` for example without any luck, if you would please post a working answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section about [Bracket Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS) which explains how to search for characters within a string to replace

but this should work for you

```
UPDATE __table__ SET __column__ = regexp_replace( __column__, E'[\\s,;:]','_','g')
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I'm surprised they didn't word it to include `array` at least to refer to bracket in the bracket sense though if someone asks this question they'll at least find this Q/A. Thanks for linking to the documentation too; Table 9-16 included details about \s for space.

Answer (score 3):

[`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.23.1.1.1) is powerful, versatile ... and slow.

Use the plain (less powerful and versatile) [`replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.29.1.1.1) where possible, it's faster.

For the simple case at hand (replace each single character in a list with another single character) use [**`translate()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.40.1.1.1) - even simpler and faster. And also less error prone.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    col =  translate(col, ',;: ', '____')
WHERE  col <> translate(col, ',;: ', '____'); -- avoid empty updates
```

Only update rows that actually change. It's a common (possibly expensive) mistake to update all rows unconditionally. Details:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Note that `' '` only replaces the space character (`' '`), while the class shorthand [`\s`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) in a regular expression matches all [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) of the the character class `[[:space:]]`.