# Apply `trim()` and `regexp_replace()` on text array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, trim

I am trying to transform a PostgreSQL text array into one where each value is replaced by one where each white space is surrounded by a character on each side. In other words, I am trying to apply `trim()` and `regexp_replace()` on each value in a text array. This is all done (among other things) inside a database function.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION manipulate_array(multiplevalues text[])
    RETURNS text[] AS 
    $BODY$
        DECLARE 
            singlevalue text;

        BEGIN
            FOREACH singlevalue IN ARRAY multiplevalues LOOP
                SELECT trim(regexp_replace(singlevalue, '\s+', ' ', 'g')) INTO singlevalue;
            END LOOP;

            RETURN multiplevalues;
        END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION manipulate_array(multiplevalues text[]) OWNER TO username;
```

Unfortunately, when I call the function with `multiplevalues = '{" red ", "  blue ", "  Ye    llow     "}'` as one of the arguments the returned value is the exact same text array. How do I get `'{"red", "blue", "yellow"}'` as a return value?

I have been staring at the definitions for `trim()`, `regexp_replace()` and the `FOREACH` loop for a while now, and I might just need a check from someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never changes the `multiplevalues` array. It just changes each element, then throws that new value away.

You need a variable where you can aggregate your results into:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION manipulate_array(multiplevalues text[])
RETURNS text[] AS 
$BODY$
  DECLARE 
    singlevalue text;
    l_result text[] := '{}'::text[]; -- initialize with an empty array
  BEGIN
    FOREACH singlevalue IN ARRAY multiplevalues LOOP
        SELECT trim(regexp_replace(singlevalue, '\s+', ' ', 'g')) INTO singlevalue;
        l_result := l_result || singlevalue; -- append to the result
    END LOOP;

    RETURN l_result; -- return the new array, not the old one
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

---

But this can be done a bit simpler using a unnest and array_agg and a plain SQL function (rather then PL/pgSQL)

You need to first unnest the array, trim the values and the aggregate that back into an array.

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but this will trim all values inside the array and return a new one:

```
create function trim_all(p_values text[])
  returns text[]
as
$$
  select array_agg(trim(regexp_replace(t.v, '\s+', ' ', 'g')) order by t.nr)
    from unnest(p_values) with ordinality as t(v, nr);
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for both your first and second answer. This works (and makes a lot of sense)!

Answer (score 1):

A couple more improvements:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION trim_all1(text[])
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT regexp_replace(trim(elem), '\s+', ' ', 'g')
   FROM   unnest($1) elem
   )
$func$;
```

It's typically faster to apply the cheap `trim()` before the expensive `regexp_replace()`.

A simple [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) is faster than `array_agg()` to aggregate a *single* array.

Make the function `IMMUTABLE` (because it is). Faster in certain contexts and can be used in indexes, etc. See:

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)

Add `PARALLEL SAFE` in Postgres 9.6 or later, because the function qualifies.

If you are dealing with **plain space characters** exclusively, further simplify:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION trim_all2(text[])
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT regexp_replace(trim(elem), '  +', ' ', 'g')
   FROM   unnest($1) elem
   )
$func$;
```

Regular expressions are comparatively expensive. If you further *know* that there are never more than *n* consecutive space characters, you can make do with simple `replace()`. A couple of nested calls are still cheaper. For **max. 8 consecutive spaces**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trim_all3(text[])
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT replace(replace(replace(
             trim(elem)
           , '     ', ' ')     -- 5   
           , '   '  , ' ')     -- 3
           , '  '   , ' ')     -- 2
   FROM   unnest($1) elem
   )
$func$;
```

In my tests on pg 9.5 each is faster than the previous version and the last one is more than twice as fast as [@a_horse's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39236311/939860).

Related:

- [Find multiple strings and replace with single string in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691393/find-multiple-strings-and-replace-with-single-string-in-postgres/27696968#27696968)

#### Does it retain the original order of elements?

The SQL standard would allow *any* order without explicit `ORDER BY`. But in this simple arrangement, Postgres will keep the original order of elements. See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Comment: Interesting. Does the `array(...)` version retain the ordering of the elements in the array?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, but that's not warranted by the SQL standard. It's an implementation detail - that's not going to change for the simple case.

Comment: The reason I chose the `array_agg()` was because I could retain the order of the original entries in the array through the `ordinality` and an `order by`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You can do the same with an array constructor. I only chose to drop it, because we can, and it saves a bit of time. Adding `ORDER BY` is cleaner either way. The OP also did not explicitly specify whether the order of elements needs to be preserved.